# referencing System.Windows.Automation

Tags: c#, .net, dll, automation

I wanted to try out some of the automation stuff available through [BugSlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163465.aspx#S1), but am having problems with the references.

I'm trying to figure out how to reference the System.Windows.Automation library in visual studio.  I have the .NET Framework v3.5 installed, and VS 2008, but neither the UIAutomationClient nor System.Windows.Automation appear as a reference option in either the .NET or COM tabs for the references.

I can see the dll if I navigate to `C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationClient\3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35` through the command prompt, but if I browse to the assembly in Visual Studio, I can't actually get to the dlls.

Have I overlooked a simple way to include this in my project?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `UIAutomationClient.dll` is located in this folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0
```

If you can't find in your  `Add Reference->.Net` tab, then you have to use the `Browse` tab to go to the given path, and add the assembly (Right Click on the `References`, choose `add reference`, click `browse` tab).

Comment: that directory only has one dll on my system, not the one I was looking for.  However the "en" folder contains an XML file for the UIAutomationClient.

I was able to use a cmd window to manually copy the dll from the GAC to a place where I can access it... it seems to work doing that.  I couldn't get at it using explorer though.

Comment: In that case maybe you have to reinstall .net 3.5 and vs 2008

Comment: This didn't work for me (no such DLL in that folder), but the answer proved by @sharmila worked

Comment: dotnet : `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\7.0.7\UIAutomationClient.dll` . Replace `7.0.7` with your preferred version of dotnet.

Answer (score 19):

add Uiautomationclient dll present under .net tab

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015, and targeting to .NET 4.5. None of the answers worked for me. Here's what I had to do (after many minutes of looking through Add References -> Assemblies -> Framework and playing around. The reference I added is "UIAutomationClient". (There isn't any System.Windows.Automation" assembly in my list. Note that I also see assemblies "UIAutomationProvider", "UIAutomationTypes", and "UIAutomationClientsideProviders", but I didn't try any of those.)

Anyway, once I got the reference to "UIAutomationClient" added, then the `using System.Windows.Automation` actually worked okay.

Answer (score 2):

For .Net coreapp 3.1, my fix is adding UseWPF into PropertyGroup of csproj file.

`<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2015, you need to reference the UIAutomationProvider dll  to use this Provider namespace. Just add a reference to this dll in your references folder. It's available in the Framework Assemblies of .NET.