# Windows Logon Dialog by Watin

Tags: c#, watin

We have an automation test running on IE using WatiN. This test requires handling the logon dialog.
How I should process it by Watin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 7, the Logon handler became a WPF component and no longer a part of the IE. I think this even applies to IE8 or higher already.

Below is the code we use for handeling these  dialogs. It's something I wrote myself, so feel free to use it, as long as credit is given where due.

```
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Linq;
using WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers;
using WatiN.Core.Native.Windows;

namespace DialogHandlers
{
    public class Windows7LogonDialogHandler : LogonDialogHandler
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private readonly string _mUsername;
        private readonly string _mPassword;
        private readonly AndCondition _mListCondition = new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));
        private readonly AndCondition _mEditCondition = new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
        private readonly AndCondition _mButtonConditions = new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button));

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public Windows7LogonDialogHandler(string username, string password)
            : base(username, password)
        {
            _mUsername = username;
            _mPassword = password;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Members

        public override bool HandleDialog(Window window)
        {
            if (CanHandleDialog(window))
            {
                var win = AutomationElement.FromHandle(window.Hwnd);
                var lists = win.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, _mListCondition);
                var buttons = win.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, _mButtonConditions);
                var another = (from AutomationElement list in lists
                               where list.Current.ClassName == "UserTile"
                               where list.Current.Name == "Use another account"
                               select list).First();
                another.SetFocus();

                foreach (var edit in from AutomationElement list in lists
                                     where list.Current.ClassName == "UserTile"
                                     select list.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, _mEditCondition)
                                         into edits
                                         from AutomationElement edit in edits
                                         select edit)
                {
                    if (edit.Current.Name.Contains("User name"))
                    {
                        edit.SetFocus();
                        var usernamePattern = edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                        if (usernamePattern != null) usernamePattern.SetValue(_mUsername);
                    }
                    if (edit.Current.Name.Contains("Password"))
                    {
                        edit.SetFocus();
                        var passwordPattern = edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                        if (passwordPattern != null) passwordPattern.SetValue(_mPassword);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var submitPattern in from AutomationElement button in buttons
                                              where button.Current.AutomationId == "SubmitButton"
                                              select button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern)
                {
                    submitPattern.Invoke();
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override bool CanHandleDialog(Window window)
        {
            return window.ClassName == "#32770";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but using `System.Windows.Automation;` is missing in my VS. What reference should I add?

Comment: I add `UIAutomationClient.dll` reference to project and now I have following error:
`The name 'ControlType' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: adding a reference to UIAutomationClient.dll should be enough, but it's possible the ControlType is in a namespace deeper. Depends what you already include in your project.

Comment: I add `UIAutomationClient.dll` and `UIAutomationTypes.dll` and then project compiled.

Comment: So project is compiled but test is failed because login/password are not entered in fields on logon form :(

`public class Class1
  {
    [Test]
    public void LoginToSite()
    {
      using (var browser = new IE("https://mysite.net/main.aspx"))
      {
        browser.DialogWatcher.Add(new UIModel.Windows7LogonDialogHandler(@"domain\login", "password"));
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: If you have alreadya Logonghandler registered, you need to remove it first before adding the new one.

Comment: I'm not clearly understand what do you mean `If you have alreadya Logonghandler registered, you need to remove it first before adding the new one.`

Comment: check in your watin code if you register another dialoghandler. We had this problem in our code because we had registered a dialoghandle, and could not get ours to work, so now when we register our dialoghandler, we unregister whatever is regsitered in watin, and then add ours.


Sort of like dealing with events.

Comment: I have no other code except those I posted and your class `Windows7LogonDialogHandler`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7228/discussion-between-algot-and-nekonova)

Comment: I replaced code above with following and it works, but I still don't understand why code above doesn't work ` public class Class1
  {
    private string login = "user";
    private string password = "password";

    [Test]
    public void Should_start_google()
    {
      Browser browser = new IE();
      WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.LogonDialogHandler ldh = new UIModel.Windows7LogonDialogHandler(login, password);
      browser.DialogWatcher.Add(ldh);

      // Code
      browser.GoTo("https://mysite.net");
    }
  }`

Comment: In my case the dialog did not have 'Use Another Account', the name was empty, deleting this line fixed it: where list.Current.Name == "Use another account".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Browser browser = new IE();
WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.LogonDialogHandler ldh = 
        new WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.LogonDialogHandler("UserName","Password");
browser.DialogWatcher.Add(ldh);
browser.ShowWindow(NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.Maximize);
browser.GoTo("http://www.yoururl.com");
```

However, if you are using Windows 7 you will probably need to [look deeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841120/watin-logondialoghandlers-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7)

Comment: I try to use advice you give, but there are many reference errors. Many operators could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a long time since this question has been answered, but I was having some trouble trying to use this code along with the IE11 (also at a browser configured with the PT-BR language), so I'd like to leave here my mods for those who might be interested or have been struggling with this as well.
*sorry for my bad English!

**watin ie11 authenticationdialog

public class Windows7LogonDialogHandler : BaseDialogHandler
    {
        #region Private Fields

```
    private readonly string _mUsername;
    private readonly string _mPassword;

    private readonly AndCondition _mListCondition = new AndCondition(
                                                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true),
                                                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.List));

    private readonly AndCondition _mListItemsCondition = new AndCondition(
                                                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true),
                                                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));

    private readonly AndCondition _mEditCondition = new AndCondition(
                                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true),
                                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));

    private readonly AndCondition _mButtonConditions = new AndCondition(
                                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true), 
                                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button));

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public Windows7LogonDialogHandler(string username, string password)
    {
        _mUsername = username;
        _mPassword = password;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Members

    public override bool HandleDialog(Window window)
    {
        if (CanHandleDialog(window))
        {
            var win = AutomationElement.FromHandle(window.Hwnd);

            var lists = win.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, _mListItemsCondition);
            var buttons = win.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, _mButtonConditions);

            var another = (from AutomationElement list in lists
                           where list.Current.ClassName == "UserTile"
                           where list.Current.Name == "Use another account"
                           select list).FirstOrDefault();
            if (another != null) another.SetFocus();

            foreach (var edit in from AutomationElement list in lists
                                 where list.Current.ClassName.Contains("UserTile")
                                 select list.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, _mEditCondition)
                                     into edits
                                     from AutomationElement edit in edits
                                     select edit)
            {
                if (edit.Current.Name.Contains("User name") || edit.Current.Name.Contains("Nome de usuário"))
                {
                    edit.SetFocus();
                    var usernamePattern = edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                    if (usernamePattern != null) usernamePattern.SetValue(_mUsername);
                }
                if (edit.Current.Name.Contains("Password") || edit.Current.Name.Contains("Senha"))
                {
                    edit.SetFocus();
                    var passwordPattern = edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                    if (passwordPattern != null) passwordPattern.SetValue(_mPassword);
                }
            }

            foreach (var submitPattern in from AutomationElement button in buttons
                                          where button.Current.AutomationId == "SubmitButton"
                                          select button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern)
            {
                submitPattern.Invoke();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanHandleDialog(Window window)
    {
        return window.ClassName == "#32770";
    }

    #endregion
}
```