# Login to site using watin - c#

Tags: c#, watin

The test site I have displays a pop up box to enter user credentials. I can log in to that site using

```
private CredentialCache GetCredential(LoginData loginData)
{

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
    CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(loginData.LoginURL), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(loginData.LoginUserName, loginData.LoginPwd));
    return credentialCache;
}

//above code is thanks to another post on SO

public void SiteLogin(LoginData loginData)
{
    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(loginData.LoginURL) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ContentLength = 0;

    request.Credentials = GetCredential(loginData);
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;



    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string testString = reader.ReadToEnd(); //see what response is here, only for initial coding

}
```

I do not have access to the test web site so I do not know what the names of the controls are for the login pop up.

How do i perform similar step with watin?

Comment: @usr: but since it is a pop up , which shows up when i hit the url, before any page is displayed how would i perform this? This is more like a security dialog that pop ups

Comment: I believe, you are looking for information on how to handle a windows login dialog that pops up when you access the site. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841120/watin-logondialoghandlers-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7