# Windows security dialog issue

Tags: c#, watin

I have an issue with handling windows security popup in Win7 with WatiN. I'm trying the solution from here: 
  [1]: [WatiN LogonDialogHandlers not working correctly in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841120/watin-logondialoghandlers-not-working-correctly-in-windows-7) (the last answer). Use the code as is without modifications, my call:

```
Ie.DialogWatcher.Add(new Windows7LogonDialogHandler(user, passw));
Ie.GoTo(url);
```

but get the error:

```
Exception was thrown while DialogWatcher called HandleDialog: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

at this point:

```
var another = (from AutomationElement list in lists
                               where list.Current.ClassName == "UserTile"
                               where list.Current.Name == "Use another account"
                               select list).First();
```

What I missed?

Comment: Try `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `.First()` - that way, it will return `null` if there are no matching items, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: With .FirstOrDefault() I get NullReferenceException at  another.SetFocus();

Comment: That's because `.FirstOrDefault()` is returning `null`, as there are no matching items in the list.